# Error when trying to configure JSS connected Demo

Tags: jss

I am trying to configure https://jss.sitecore.com/connected-demo/ in my system.

I ran two commands `npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli` and `npm install`

After this I ran `jss start:connected` command. This is where the system throws error

[image]

Comment: Check your API key's CORS settings, looks like it's blocking your calls from localhost.

Comment: Can you access your site https://sc93sc.dev.local and make sure the ssl work. Since it is local instance make sure you accept the certificate and try again

Answer (score 0):

Looks like somethings wrong with API key settings(`/sitecore/system/Settings/Services/API Keys/Key`).

Below are the settings which are mentioned in [Jss Document](https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/getting-started/app-deployment)

[image]

Comment: I have tried with * and  blank in the `CORS Origins` field but it didn't work

Comment: Is this URL working "http://your-sitecore-instance/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey=" ?

Comment: yes it works for me

Comment: Can you please share your scjssconfig.json and sitecore/config/<app>.config?